# How to change the user to make pull requests in Bitbucket using jenkins

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, bitbucket

- I have a pipeline to create two new branches and push them to BitBucket, then create a new pull request.
- The jenkins pipeline is running on a linux slave.
- I've setup the credential to bitbucket repo in jenkins credentials.

So far creating new branches and pushing them to BitBucket works finely with my credentials.

```
sh script: "git init"
sh script: "git add *"
sh script: 'git commit -m "new branch created"'
sh script: "git checkout -b ${new_branch}"
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
                   credentialsId: 'mycred',
                   usernameVariable: 'username',
                   passwordVariable: 'pass']]){
sh('git push https://${username}:${pass}@bitbucket.example.com:8080/scm/user/reponame ${new_branch})
```

Like this I create and push two new branches ${new_branch}, ${new_branch2}. Even though only my credentials `mycred` has access to the repo, two branches gets pushed with cloud user. In commit section it shows "cloud user"

Then I'm trying to create a pull request from ${new_branch} to ${new_branch2}.

When I try to create a pull request with my credentials using a curl, it says

```
{"errors":[{"context": null,"message":"Authentication failed. please check your credentials and try again.","exceptionName":"com.atlassian.bitbucket.auth.IncorrectPasswordAuthenticationException"}]}
```

My curl command using bitbucket api is,

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
                   credentialsId: 'mycred',
                   usernameVariable: 'username',
                   passwordVariable: 'pass']]){
sh """curl --insecure -X POST https://${username}:${pass}@bitbucket.example.com:8080/rest/api/1.0/repos/myrepo/pull-request?create\
-H 'Content-Type:application/jason'\
-u ${username}:${pass}\
-d '{"title":"testpullreq",\
        "description":"sampledescription",\
        "state":"open",\
        "open":true,\
        "closed":false,\
        "fromRef":{\
            "id":"refs/heads/${new_branch}",\
            "repository":{\
            "slug":"branch-to-pr",\
            "name":"branch-To-PR",\
            }\
         },\
        "toRef":{\
           "id":"refs/heads/${new_branch2}",\
            "repository":{\
            "slug":"branch-to-pr2",\
            "name":"branch-To-PR2",\
           }\
       },\
       "locked":false,\
       "reviewers":[\
                   {\
                   "user":{\
                   "name":"myemail@example.com"\
                    }\
                 }\
              ]\
         }' """
```

So curl command also works fine, the error is it says I don't have authentication permission, and that's because the PR tries to get made using my slave. I need to do this with my user account (mycred).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your issue occurs because `curl` is a command that runs within the Jenkins host. Therefore, it uses the credentials already present in the host when running the command.

You can consider using the [HttpRequest](https://github.com/jenkinsci/http-request-plugin) plugin instead. The plugin allows you to use your specified credentials to send the post request with a body. The difference is that no system commands are used, so the command is sent independent of the credentials already present in the host. This should force Jenkins to use your `mycred` credentials.